# Change text style based on search bar text

Tags: flutter

I would like to change the style of the text according to what I enter in the search bar, that is, search if it matches and change dynamically. Something like that.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PVMu.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) to specify different styles for each text segment:

```
RichText(text: TextSpan(children: [
  TextSpan(text: 'Hello', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
  TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
]));
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I do it dynamically? That is, it matches what I type in the search bar.

Comment: Try regex and then built the list out of the matchings.